# Connecting to Azure database when running web application locally

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have been developing a basic Azure based web application and have run into a problem. The application queries a database that is hosted on Azure and returns the values to the user. When I run the application locally on my private wifi network and when I deploy the application to Azure, it runs fine and the queries are returned correctly. However, when I run the application locally on my companys wifi, I get the following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. 
The server was not found or was not accessible.
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
(provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)
```

Can anyone tell me if there is any additional code I need to add or what exception I need to ask to be put in the company's firewall in order to allow me to run and test the application locally?

Comment: Did you configure firewall rules for SQL Azure?

Comment: Yes. When I click on "Set up Windows Azure firewall rules for this IP address", it says "The current IP address 193.X.XXX.XXX already has a Windows Azure firewall rule. You should be able to connect to Windows Azure from this computer."

Comment: 'Your company wifi' is probably having a different IP that is not configured...

Comment: Also, Azure databases are talked to via port 1433. Most corporate firewalls won't have that open. Can you connect to it via SSMS from your work machine? Or telnet to it on 1433?

Comment: @simonatrcl Thank you. Finally got an exception put in the corporate firewall and it works fine.